# jQuery Datatables from array of object api doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, datatables

I'm trying to use jQuery DataTables on my project. But I'm having a problem because it doesn't work with my code.

Here's my sample api

```
{
    "single": [
     {
         "name": "Jessica"
     }, 
     {
         "name": "John"
     },{
         "name": "Jasmine"
     }
    ],
    "married": [
     {
         "name": "Alpa"
     }, 
     {
         "name": "Haifa"
     },{
         "name": "Teala"
     }
    ]
}
```

Here's my sample `Datatables` but it doesn't work.

```
    $('#table').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        ajax: {
           url: 'http://localhost:22222/api/status/',
           method: 'GET',
           xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
              }
           },
           columns: [
              { data: "single.name"}
           ]
        });
    });
```

I have error on the console that says

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that source data that you're trying to feed to DataTables is not structured properly - in array/object that you use as a source data, each entry must correspond to table row.

So, you need either modify data format server-side (more preferably), or you may postprocess it user-end:

```js
var srcData = {
    "single": [
     {
         "name": "Jessica"
     }, 
     {
         "name": "John"
     },{
         "name": "Jasmine"
     }
    ],
    "married": [
     {
         "name": "Alpa"
     }, 
     {
         "name": "Haifa"
     },{
         "name": "Teala"
     }
    ]
};
//Transform srcData so each entry corresponds to table row
const transformData = data => {
 let res = [];
  data.single.forEach(entry => res.push({name:entry.name,status:'single'}));
  data.married.forEach(entry => res.push({name:entry.name,status:'married'}));
  return res;
};

srcData = transformData(srcData);

//Render datatable itself
$('#mytable').DataTable({
 data: srcData,
  sDom: 't',
  columns: [{title:'Name', data:'name'},{title:'Status', data:'status'}]
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But my data is from api

Comment: as being said, there's no problem to transform your data user-end either - just like in this example